# Poincare duality gives the forms with integer integral along loops

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-forms

Let $X$ be a surface. We know for any loop $\gamma$ we can find a form $\alpha$ such that integral along $\gamma$ equals integral wedge $\alpha$ on the surface. My question is, are these forms ($\alpha$, get from duality) exactly those which integral along every loop is an integer?

I checked this is true for torus, so I want to know if is true in general.

Comment: Do you want $\alpha$ to be a $1$ form? Then you want $\int_\gamma \alpha$ to be the same as $\int_X \kappa\wedge\alpha$ where $\kappa$ is what?

Comment: @s.harp Yes $\alpha$ is 1 form, and for all 1 form $\beta$, $\int_\gamma \beta =\int_X \beta \wedge \alpha$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, the Poincaré dual of a loop always gives an integer when integrated on any loop.

Let $C$ be a smooth loop on a compact oriented smooth surface $X$. The Poincaré dual $\eta_C$ of $C$ defines a cohomology class $[\eta_C] \in H^1(X)$ with the property that for any $\omega \in H^1(X)$,$$\int_C \omega = \int_X \omega \wedge \eta_C.$$**Claim.** *For any loop $C'$, $\int_{C'} \eta_C$ is an integer.*

*Proof.* We have$$\int_{C'} \eta_C = \int_X \eta_C \wedge \eta_{C'} = \#(C \cdot C')$$because the wedge product is dual to intersection of cycles. The intersection of two cycles is always an integer.$$\tag*{$\square$}$$

> What is $\#(C \cdot C')$ and why $\int_X \eta_C \wedge \eta_{C'} = \#(C \cdot C')$?

$\text{}$1. $\#(C \cdot C')$ is the intersection number of the two oriented curves $C$ and $C'$. They can be jiggled slightly  so that they become transversal. In that case, each intersection point is counted with multiplicity $+1$ or $-1$ depending on the orientations of $C$ and $C'$. Thus, the intersection number is always an integer.

You can find a nice discussion of intersection theory in Guillemin and Pollack's "Differential Topology" or in Griffiths and Harris's "Principles of Algebraic Geometry".

$\text{}$2. In one version of Poincaré duality, closed forms are dual to cycles and under this duality, the wedge product of closed forms correspond to the intersection of cycles. I am not sure where this is discussed—maybe Griffiths and Harris's "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" or some text on algebraic topology.

Comment: What is $\#(C \cdot C')$ and why $\int_X \eta_C \wedge \eta_{C'} = \#(C \cdot C')$?

Comment: Thanks! And this also solved the other part of the question. Let $\alpha$ be a one form with integer integral along every loop, in fact we only need to check this on a basis of $H_1(X)$, and by construct a loop intersecting these basis with the given integers (you can draw a picture to see this is possible) we get a one form $\beta$. Both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are closed one form and there difference has zero integral along every loop, hence is exact.